# Prove domain of every solution to certain system of ode’s contains some interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I’am asked to prove that:

i)
The domain of every solution to the ODE system \begin{cases}
\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x(x^2+xy+1)\\
\dfrac{dy}{dt}=y(y^2+xy+1)
\end{cases}
contains $(-\infty,0]$,

and

ii) $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to-\infty}\left(x^2+y^2\right)=0$

The second part (ii) I know how to prove, but how one can prove the domain part (i)? I have no clue.

Comment: Is the second equation supposed to specify $dy/dt?$

Comment: I meant is your second DE supposed to be $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=y(y^2+xy+1)$ instead of $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=y(y^2+xy+1)?$ It would be very odd to have $dx/dt$ equal to two different things like that.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Oh yeah. Thank you.

Comment: Can you see any symmetry in the equation for $dy/dx$?

Comment: What can you tell about the derivatives of the polar coordinates? That would be the natural thing to do as the long-term behavior of the radius (square) is to be examined.

Comment: @LutzL the parimetrization in polar coord-s, is non-trivial here and not needed for the second part of the question. I am wondering how would you use it for proving i) part. As we are asked to prove that there exist solution (x(t),y(t)) for every $t\in(-\infty,0)$

Comment: @complexmanifold What I see is that $dy/dx=\frac{y(y^2+xy+1)}{x(x^2+xy+1}$ I cannot spot the symmetry though

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to actually compute $$
\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2)=2x^2(x^2+xy+1)+2y^2(y^2+xy+1)=2(x^4+y^4)+2(xy+1)(x^2+y^2)
$$
In polar coordinates that gives
$$
\frac{d}{dt} r^2=2r^4-r^4\sin^2(2\theta)+r^4\sin(2θ)+2r^2=(1+\sin(2θ))(2-\sin(2θ))r^4+2r^2\ge 2r^2
$$
Thus the in the radial component of the vector field always points outward, which in turn means that the evolution in negative time moves everywhere towards smaller radii, towards the origin.

```
WA: streamplot[{x*(x^2+xy+1),y*(y^2+xy+1)}, {x,-9.,9.}, {y,-9.,9.}]
```

[image: stream plot by wolfram alpha]

As the solution for negative times is bounded by its radius at $t=0$, it exists for all times $t\in(-\infty, 0]$. The solution of an autonomous ODE can only cease to be at a finite time if it diverges towards infinity when approaching that time.

The evolution in negative time can also be given a quantitative bound, $r(t)\le r(0)e^t$ for $t<0$.